# iOS TableView error : This class is not key value > coding-compliant for the key tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, crash

I am getting the following error

> 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key tableView.'

This is the following property I am using to hook to my UITableView in .xib file. I've done this a thousand times, but for some reason it isn't working for me anymore.

```
@property (nonatomic,weak )IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

There is no exclamation mark or anything. I don't understand why this error is occurring for me. I must be missing something small here.

I posted a pic below to show proof of no exlamation mark or anything.

[image]

Comment: Maybe delete the connection in IB and reconnect?

Comment: @Phillip. I did that and nothing happened. I am still getting the same error

Comment: By "nothing" you mean you still get the same error?

Comment: @Phillp Yes, nothing has changed.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Main.Storyboard and command click on the first icon. If you have any outlets or actions with yellow errors redo them.